# ArcGIS Runtime .NET / Setting Viewpoint based on Google Map Co-ords

Tags: .net, arcgis-runtime

I am new to GIS tools.

The following code runs inside a mouse click handler, and should center the map on the given co-ordinate location.

The co-ordinates are taken from Google Maps web view, and my understanding is that 3857 is the spatial reference for these co-ordinates.

Currently, this code moves the map to a very different location and sets the scale to something completely different.

```
var point = new MapPoint
(
    -37.808934,
    144.975170,
    SpatialReference.Create(3857)  
);

var extent = new ViewpointCenter(point, 3000);

MyMapView.SetView(extent);
```

Does ArcGIS automatically convert the co-ordinates from that space to the maps spatial reference, or is that something I need to do myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, I was required to convert the co-ordinates in degrees to metres using ConvertCoordinate.FromDecimalDegrees(...) before passing them to the Viewpoint constructor.